# Loop while dynamically scraping - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I want to try to make realtime **scrapes** which have separate intervals. For example, the last data I scrape is T = 1 then it will loop once every 6 hours, T = 2 then it will loop 1 hour once and T = 3 then it will loop once every 1 minute.

But after I thought about the logic, I was confused about how to implement it.

where I make T as a reference, here is an example of the data.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H427J.png

I will try to share the code snippet that I made.

```
headers = ["Year", "Month", "Day", "Hour", "Minute", "Second", "T", "Height"]
page = requests.get('https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/station_page.php?station=52406')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
datas = []
dt = soup.find_all('textarea')[0].text
datas = dt.split('\n')[2:-1]

#membaca scrape to to array dan membaca data ke6
arr = []
arr = np.array([datas])

def listToString(s):
    str1 = ""
    for ele in s:
        str1 += ele
    return str1

coba = []
for item_list in arr:
    item_string = listToString(item_list)
    coba.append(item_string.split()[6])
print(coba)
#-----------------------------------------------
#perulangan interval data T
while True:
    if coba[0] == 1:
        while True:
            page = requests.get('https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/station_page.php?station=52406')
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
            datas1 = []
            dt = soup.find_all('textarea')[0].text
            datas1 = dt.split('\n')[2:-1]

            with open("52406.csv", "w") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n")
                writer.writerow(headers)
    
                for line in soup.select_one("#data").text.split("\n"):
                    if re.fullmatch(r"[\d. ]{30}", line) and len(line.split()) == len(headers):
                        writer.writerow(line.split())
                    
        print('Data 1')
        addDate()
        insertSQL()
    time.sleep(3600)
    break

    if coba[0] == 2:
        while True:
            page = requests.get('https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/station_page.php?station=52406')
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
            datas1 = []
            dt = soup.find_all('textarea')[0].text
            datas1 = dt.split('\n')[2:-1]

            with open("52406.csv", "w") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n")
                writer.writerow(headers)
    
                for line in soup.select_one("#data").text.split("\n"):
                    if re.fullmatch(r"[\d. ]{30}", line) and len(line.split()) == len(headers):
                        writer.writerow(line.split())
                    
        print('Data 1')
        addDate()
        insertSQL()
    time.sleep(3600)
    break
    
    if coba[0] == 3:
        while True:
            page = requests.get('https://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/station_page.php?station=52406')
            soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
            datas1 = []
            dt = soup.find_all('textarea')[0].text
            datas1 = dt.split('\n')[2:-1]

            with open("52406.csv", "w") as f:
                writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n")
                writer.writerow(headers)
    
                for line in soup.select_one("#data").text.split("\n"):
                    if re.fullmatch(r"[\d. ]{30}", line) and len(line.split()) == len(headers):
                        writer.writerow(line.split())
                    
        print('Data 1')
        addDate()
        insertSQL()
    time.sleep(3600)
    break
```

Comment: you could use yield

Comment: FYI it’s scraping not scrapping. Scrapping means throwing things away like rbbish.

Comment: scrap can also be to quarrel or fight. A fight every 6 hours or less. Eek.

Comment: @QHarr Do you have a solution so that loops don't collide?

Comment: Prime numbers depending on time to complete? Run on separate threads?

Comment: @QHarr run separately? for the loop?